# SSL certificate in Directadmin not working

Tags: ssl, certificate

I'm trying to install a Comodo SSL certificate on a shared server, which has directadmin installed. I have assigned the user an unique ip address, made the CSR request and uploaded the certificate.

In directadmin I get the response that both the certificate and private key are saved. Unfortunately, when I browse to the https://www.domain.com I get a SSL error, saying that the certificate is untrusted, because it is self-signed.

I'm confused why this error occurs. It seems to me that I followed the correct steps to install the Comodo ssl certificate. I also tried deleting the private key and certificate through the command line on the server. But this does not seem to resolve the error.

What direction should I be looking into solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you installed the intermediate certificate. You have to list one or more intermediate certificates in the field for your public key.

You can also use the GlobalSign OneClickSSL plugin for DirectAdmin and let the plugin do everything for you automatically.

See: https://www.globalsign.com/ssl/oneclickssl/directadmin/

And: http://www.youtube.com/#/watch?v=tVP9i6Ing1M

Comment: The OP has already purchased a Comodo SLL. The GlobalSign OneClickSSL plugin only works for their service, since it asks for one of their own vouchers to start off. Do you work for GlobalSign by any chance?